# Slide animation elements one at a time?

Tags: css

I'm trying to slide a few elements one after the other on the page.

Basically, I need to slide the first element in, and then the second after and then the third one etc etc.

**Something like this:**

[image]

This is what i have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/npvsrkcy/3/

In the fiddle above, all the elements/images will slide in all at the same time which is not what i am looking for.

This is my entire code:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin: 1em;
    animation: slide 4s 1;
  width:100%;
}
@keyframes slide {
    from { right: -150%; }
    to { right: 0%; }
}
```

Could someone please advise on this?

**EDIT:**

Ok, since I'm trying to use the slide animation on dynamically created elements, I can't use the normal nth-child~(number) scenario.

So I tried to do this:

```
img:nth-child(1n+3) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
   animation-delay: 0;
}

img:nth-child(2n+2) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
   animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

img:nth-child(3n+3) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
   animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

but that seems to only work for the first 3 elements/images!

This is the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npvsrkcy/9/

Answer (score 1):

You might try to leverage the nth-child(number) selector to delay the animation, like so:

```
img {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 0%;
   margin: 1em;
   animation: slide 4s 1;
   width:100%;
   /* Fix the elements being visible before the animation */
   opacity: 0;
   /* After the animation remain visible */
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
   animation-delay: 0;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
   animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide {
from { right: -150%; opacity: 0;}
to { right: 0%; opacity: 1; }
}
```

This would delay the animation of the second and third image element by the set amount of seconds.

Hope it helps!

Edit: just played with the fiddle, and it seems that an edit to the animation would be desirable to prevent them from showing before loading. Allow me to come up with a fix;
Edit 2: Fixed it by setting the animation-fill-mode to forwards and added an opacity effect. Another solution would be to place the image off-screen to starty with.

PS. Some further info:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: I can't use the nth-child(number) because the elements are created dynamically so i wouldn't know how many elements/images there could be.

Comment: Ah I see, that does complicate the matter. I believe that considering the elements are created dynamically you cannot apply a CSS-only solution and thus you'll have to resort to a JS solution. However, I'm not quite sufficiently versed in JS to assist with that :/
Hope you find a solution to the matter though! Good luck!

Comment: I did, I'm now thinking in the direction of having them slide into view whenever they are in the viewport; or is a JS solution completely undesirable? In addition, it's not pretty but you could simply define the elements till the maximum amount of elements you expect to be on a page (i.e., till :nth-child(15). Unless you're using some infinite-scroll, in which case that wouldn't work.

Comment: I was referring to the use of `img:nth-child(2n+2) {..}` etc etc as opposed to `img:nth-child(2) {...}` etc.

Comment: Well that is possible, but they would still all slide in as quick as the first, second and third elements, thus all 1/3 would slide in at no delay, all 2/3 would slide in at the second delay and all 3/3 would slide in at the third delay... I believe the only way to prevent this behavior is to define them till the most reasonable amount you can expect, or to have them slide in whenever they come into the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
    img {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin: 1em;
        animation: Aslide 4s 1;
      width:100%;
    }

    img + img {
      animation: Bslide 4s 1;
    }

    img + img + img {
      animation: Cslide 4s 1;
    }

    @keyframes Aslide {
        0% { right: -150%; }
        33.333333% { right: 0%; }
66.666666% { right: 0%;}
        100% { right: 0%;}
    }

    @keyframes Bslide {
        0 { right: -150%; }
        33.333333% { right: -150%; }
        66.666666% { right: 0%;}
        100% { right: 0%;}
    }

    @keyframes Cslide {
        0% {  right: -150%; }
33.333333% { right: -150%; }
        66.666666% { right: -150%; }
        100% { right: 0%;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delay the animation for each div  (and) 
Add a fill-mode and set right value to -150% for img tag by default

```
img {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin: 1em;
 animation: slide 4s 1 forwards;
 width:100%;
 right: -150%;
}
img:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay:0s;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay:1s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay:2s;
}
@keyframes slide {
 from { right: -150%; }
 to { right: 0%; }
}
```